# Requested registry access is not allowed even with elevation

Tags: c#, registry, admin, elevation

I have a console program that changes the user's MAC address, but when I try to read or write to a key **even though I have administrator access,** I still get "Requested registry access is not allowed".
My code:

```
if (IsAdministrator())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ready to start. Program is started as administrator.");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program is not started as admin. Please start as admin! Press enter to exit.");
        Console.Read();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    RegistryKey root = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}");
    foreach (string s in root.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        string nicName = "";
        RegistryKey rkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\" + s, true);
        if(rkey.GetValue("DriverDesc") != null)
        {
            nicName = rkey.GetValue("DriverDesc").ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(nicName);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

IsAdministrator()

```
public static bool IsAdministrator()
    {
        var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
```

What do I do? 
Thanks!

Comment: Do the permissions on that key give read access to Administrators?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: Open regedit, navigate to the key, right-click the key in the tree and select "permissions". And check that there aren't any deny permissions at play (since they take precedence over allow)

Comment: Yeah there aren’t any deny boxes checked for any users

Comment: ...and Administrators have full control?

Comment: Yeah. Only “Users” doesn’t have full control.